# How do I update keepass2 to current version in 14.04

Tags: keepass

How do I update Keepass2 to newest version or better yet get it to update automaticaly in 14.04? The jtaylor repository does not seem to have Trusty or I don't know how to get it.

Comment: compile from source. Create a shell script to automate everything from downloading to compiling to installing to clearing the mess.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is a pretty old post, but searching for the topic I stumbled about it.
And for those of you who will do so in the future, here is an answer that worked for me.

Thanks to [Julian Taylor](https://sourceforge.net/u/jtaylor108/) (thx buddy!!) we have a working ppa for Keepass2. Here is his project page: https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329220/thread/17d1bd26/?page=2

Install it like this (via terminal):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jtaylor/keepass
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install keepass2
```

Hope it helps!

Cheers,
Nix

Comment: We sure this jtaylor guy can be trusted? I get this warning "WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!". Normally I wouldn't care too much, but we're talking about all my passwords here.

Comment: Yes, we can trust jtaylor. You can check his [launchpad profile](https://launchpad.net/~jtaylor). He is a [Ubuntu Member](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Membership).

Comment: To the maintainer of this ppa, jtaylor: 

Please update your KeePass2 ppa to include Keepass2 version 1.70.